# Convert dataframe column to datetime only if length of string is not zero

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, python-datetime

I'd like to convert a dataframe column which has a date string. But in some cases, the date string might be empty due to certain conditions. So I just want all the other rows in that column to be converted to datetime format except the rows in that particular column which might be blank. Is it possible?

What I've tried so far:

Option1:

```
df['etime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['etime'],errors='ignore').dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M')
```

Option 2:

```
    for ind in df.index:
        if (df['etime'].str.len()[ind] == 0) :
            df.loc[ind, 'etime'] = "----"
        else:
           df.loc[ind, 'etime'] = <need to convert this row to datetime>
```

Kindly provide your suggestions.

Dataframe sample:

```
data = pd.DataFrame({

    'day' : [15, 17, 20, 14, 25],

    'etime': ["20200811235205", "", "20200811215205", "20200811225205", "20200811235203"]

})
```

Comment: show data in dataframe

Comment: what does `pd.to_datetime(df['etime'],errors='ignore')` do ?

Comment: @Manakin - > It just converts to datetime on applicable rows, but does not do the formatting ''%Y-%m-%d %H:%M''

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two steps:

First, let's create a series with your datetimes and coerce the bad values into `NaTs`:

```
s = pd.to_datetime(data['etime'],errors='coerce',format='%Y%m%d%H%M%S')
```

Second, let's find any values that aren't `NaT` and replace them with your target formatting:

```
data.loc[~s.isna(),'etime'] = s.dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M')

   day             etime
0   15  2020-08-11 23:52
1   17                  
2   20  2020-08-11 21:52
3   14    20200811265205
4   25  2020-08-11 23:52
```

- assuming 26 is a typo in your hour column at index 3.

Comment: Thanks @manakin, Yes index 3 was a typo, I've corrected it now.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like:

```
df["etime"] =  df["etime"].apply(lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x,errors='ignore').strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M') if len(x) !=0 else "----")
```

Comment: Tried this, it gives me an error ===> 'AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'str'

Comment: Try it now, without the data I cannot test it.