# Turn all index values to datetime when index is both timestamp and datetime

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I want to convert index of my time series DataFrame into datetime. The problem is that some of index is timestamp and some datetime.

```
time                     C1
2020-10-18 13:38:43.349  0.046   
2020-10-18 13:52:34.104  0.099  
1602824859304            1.000   
1602824934121            0.007
```

This:    `df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time'], unit='ms')`
Yields:  `ValueError: non convertible value time with the unit 'ms'`

This:    `df["time"] =  df["time"].apply(lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x,errors='ignore').strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M') if len(x) !=0 else "----")`
Yields:  `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'strftime'`

This is a similar question but isn't applicable in my case:
[Convert dataframe column to datetime only if length of string is not zero](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63393340/convert-dataframe-column-to-datetime-only-if-length-of-string-is-not-zero)

My expected output is all index rows being datetime format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's try to identify all the rows that are timestamp and convert them separately:

```
mask = df['time'].str.contains(' ')

df['time'] = (pd.to_datetime(df.loc[mask,'time'])
                   .reindex(df.index)
                   .fillna(pd.to_datetime(df.loc[~mask, 'time'], unit='ms'))
                )
```

Output:

```
                     time     C1
0 2020-10-18 13:38:43.349  0.046
1 2020-10-18 13:52:34.104  0.099
2 2020-10-16 05:07:39.304  1.000
3 2020-10-16 05:08:54.121  0.007
```

Comment: What is `mask`?

Comment: @normal_humansorry, forgot to include that. see updated answer.